# Change to iframe in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe

https://www.gmx.net

I want to click on `Zustimmen und weiter`.

```
driver.get('https://www.gmx.net')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '/html/body/iframe')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="save-all-conditionally"]').click()
```

The code above is not working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element you are trying to access is located inside nested iframe, one iframe insde another iframe.
You should switch to the first iframe, then to the inner iframe and then to click the "Get cookies" button.
This should work:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@class="permission-core-iframe"]')))
wait.until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'plus')]")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="save-all-conditionally"]'))).click()
```

When you finished working inside that iframe you will have to switch to the default context with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```